# Decrypt a string with C# that was originally encrypted in Foxpro

Tags: c#, encryption, foxpro

I'm writting a .Net MVC program that has to be able to read strings that were encrypted by a Foxpro application. If I were doing the encryption and decryption from the start, no problem. I don't know what foxpro's Encrpyt and Decrypt methods are doing under the hood to know how to apply the same encrypt and decrypt methods in C#.

Here is the call to Encrypt in foxpro.

```
encyptedString = ENCRYPT(saltString + unencryptedString, secretkey_aes256,2,0)
```

Here is the call to Decrypt in foxpro (second line removes the salt)

```
unencryptedString = DECRYPT(encryptedString, secretkey_aes256,2,0)
unencryptedString = SUBSTR(unencryptedString, LEN(saltString) + 1)
```

I obviously know the values for the saltString and secretkey_aes256 and yes the aes256 is a clue but I don't know what the parameters 2 and 0 are doing.

Thought someone would get a kick out of solving this riddle and maybe to them it isn't even a riddle. I've been working on it for a couple of hours and I'm just not savvy enough with encrypt and decrypt to figure it out so far.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

if 2 mean AES256 and 0 means ECB, any clues as to what I'm doing wrong with the code below??

```
public string DecryptString(string encrypted)
        {
            RijndaelManaged myAES = new RijndaelManaged();
            myAES.KeySize = 256;
            myAES.BlockSize = 256;
            myAES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            myAES.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

            byte[] _key = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_secret);

            myAES.Key = _key;

            byte[] encrypted_bytes = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@encrypted.Trim());

            ICryptoTransform decrypto = myAES.CreateDecryptor();

            string decrypted = "";

            decrypted = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypto.TransformFinalBlock(encrypted_bytes, 0, encrypted.Trim().Length));

            return decrypted;
        }
```

Comment: 2 means AES256, 0 means ECB http://www.sweetpotatosoftware.com/SPSBlog/PermaLink,guid,db662a8f-d47c-46c8-b0d2-a591c20d024b.aspx

Comment: any ideas why the code I've added isn't working??

Comment: Can you give some test data? A unencrypted string, a test key and the encrypted string from foxpro, there are a few things wrong with the code, but rather than go back and forth if I have that I can try it out.

Answer (score 1):

VFP doesn't have built-in encryption and decryption, so whoever wrote the code was using a 3rd party product. Chris Diver is probably right that it was Craig Boyd's VFPEncryption.FLL. Here's the latest documentation for that library: http://www.sweetpotatosoftware.com/spsblog/2009/08/09/MajorVFPEncryptionUpdate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since there is not enough information you will need experiment a bit to find the right `BlockSize` (256 Bit?) and `IV`, I would think it is all set to 0x00 .

For the decryption itself you can use `RijndaelManaged` with `KeySize` set to 256 bits and `Mode` set to `ECB` - a good starting point is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx

Comment: thank you for the link. I will start experimenting. I editted my question to include my current non-working code. Any insight to what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

AES256 has a blocksize of 128 bits and a keysize of 256 bits. Therefore you need to set the blocksize of your RijndaelManaged instance to 128, *not* 256.